# recorrer json en php y asignar valor a campo con punto en nombre

Tags: php

tengo un json en php `"$obj"` y quiero recorrer el json y asignar "hola" al campo del json `proy_sim.name`.

```
 foreach ($obj as $data)  
        {  
            $data->fecha=date('d/m/Y',strtotime($data->fecha));
            $data->proy_sim.name="hola"; //Esto me da error.
        }
```

El error lo tengo en proy_sim.name, seguramente por el punto en el nombre, imagino que la solución sería escapar el punto y lo he intentado con "." y poniendo corchetes pero nada..

Comment: podrias hacerle un print_r($obj); para ver que trae asi te puedo ayudar mejor y pon el resultado en la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente, el problema es el punto que se usa para acceder a valores de objetos ("dot notation").

La solución es usar comillas y llaves, por ej,

```
 $data->{'proy_sim.name'}="hola"
```

Otra opción es convertir el objeto json en array. Ej.:

```
$array = (array) $obj;
$value = $array['proy_sim.name'];
```

Saludos,

---

Crédito: [Stackoverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30588149/get-json-objects-value-in-php-if-its-name-contains-dots-in-php)